# List of unique polymorphic objects

Tags: java, list, unique

I am trying to validate that a list only contains unique type of polymorphic objects. What would be a clean way to verify this?

Here's a simple example to illustrate what I am trying to do:

Given a `List<Animal> uniqueAnimals`,

I consider

```
uniqueAnimals = Arrays.asList(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Cat("Garfield"))
```

to be valid and

```
uniqueAnimals = Arrays.asList(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Dog("Pluto"), new Cat("Garfield"))
```

to be invalid

Comment: Why is the second list invalid, because it contains two dogs?

Comment: Yes the requirement is to have unique type in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getClass()` function, it returns the runtime class of this object. You can store this class in a set and use the `add` method.

The `add` method adds the element to the set if it is not already present in the set, otherwise, it returns false.

```
  public static boolean areAllUnique(List<Animal> list) {
    Set<Class> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (Animal animal : list) {
      if (!set.add(animal.getClass()))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java-8 you can use:

```
private boolean isValid(List<Animal> animals) {
    return animals.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    x -> false, (a, b) -> true, HashMap::new))
            .containsValue(true);
}
```

The collect return the name of class, with true if duplicate or false if not.

```
{Cat=false, Dog=false}
{Cat=false, Dog=true}
```

Then, you can check if the HashMap contains value true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the classes of the objects in the list are unique.  Try this.

```
static boolean isUniquePolymorphicObjects(List<Animal> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(object -> object.getClass())
        .distinct().count() == list.size();
}
```

and

```
List<Animal> uniqueAnimalsValid = Arrays.asList(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Cat("Garfield"));
System.out.println(isUniquePolymorphicObjects(uniqueAnimalsValid));

List<Animal> uniqueAnimalsInvalid = Arrays.asList(new Dog("Snoopy"), new Dog("Pluto"), new Cat("Garfield"));
System.out.println(isUniquePolymorphicObjects(uniqueAnimalsInvalid));
```

otuput:

```
true
false
```